# Image upload after cropping in jsf2.0 and primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to upload images after cropping them. I do it this way:, first upload the image  and show within the page. But the problem is that when I  crop the image and click the submit button,the corresponding image cropper bean is not called. I don't know where I'm wrong.

xhtml code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form  >
<p:panel header="FILE UPLOAD WITH CROPPER" style="width:900px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:0px">

<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{photoUploadAction.handleImageUpload}"  
        mode="advanced"   
        update="getImageId,messages"  auto="true" 

        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>  

<p:growl id="uploadMessages" showSummary="true" showDetail="true"/>

<p:outputPanel id="getImageId">

<h:panelGrid columns="2">

 <p:imageCropper id="cropperId" value="#{imageCrop.croppedImage}"
              image="images/#{photoUploadVO.imageName}"/>
  <p:graphicImage value="cropImages/#{imageCrop.imageName}" cache="false"/>
 </h:panelGrid>

   <p:commandLink value="Crop" update="getImageId" action="#{imageCrop.crop}" type="submit" />
</p:outputPanel>
</p:panel>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dint understand your question properly, up to my understanding, I think you may not created a `managedBean` for your imageCropperBean in your `faces.config`. or else just declare an annotation before the cropperBean Class `@managedBean`